# How to link logo to a custom url wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Im trying to make my logo link back to a landning page.
Ive tried to link my logo to a custom url but I crash the site every time.

Below is a snippet from the header.php any help is appreciated.

```
   <?php
     /***************************************
                SITE LOGO           
    ***************************************/
    if ( !function_exists( 'be_themes_get_header_logo_image' ) ) {
    function be_themes_get_header_logo_image() {
        global $be_themes_data;
        $logo = get_template_directory_uri().'/img/logo.png';
        if( ! empty( $be_themes_data['logo']['url'] ) ) {
            $logo = $be_themes_data['logo']['url'];
        }
        if( ! empty( $be_themes_data['logo_sticky']['url'] ) ) {
            $logo_sticky = $be_themes_data['logo_sticky']['url'];
        } else {
            $logo_sticky = $logo;
        }
        if( ! empty( $be_themes_data['logo_transparent']['url'] )) {
            $logo_transparent = $be_themes_data['logo_transparent']['url'];
        } else {
            $logo_transparent = $logo;
        }
        if( ! empty( $be_themes_data['logo_transparent_light']['url'] )) {
            $logo_transparent_light = $be_themes_data['logo_transparent_light']['url'];
        } else {
            $logo_transparent_light = $logo_transparent;
        }
        echo '<a href="'.home_url().'">';
            $post_id = be_get_page_id();
            if(is_singular( 'post' ) && is_single($post_id) && isset($be_themes_data['single_blog_hero_section_from']) && $be_themes_data['single_blog_hero_section_from'] == 'inherit_option_panel') {
                $header_transparent = $be_themes_data['single_blog_header_transparent'];
            } else if((in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) && is_product($post_id)) && isset($be_themes_data['single_shop_hero_section_from']) && $be_themes_data['single_shop_hero_section_from'] == 'inherit_option_panel') {
                $header_transparent = $be_themes_data['single_shop_header_transparent'];
            } else {
                $header_transparent = get_post_meta($post_id, 'be_themes_header_transparent', true);
            }
            if(!empty($header_transparent) && isset($header_transparent) && ('none' != $header_transparent)) {
                echo '<img class="transparent-logo dark-scheme-logo" src="'.$logo_transparent.'" alt="Logo" />';
                echo '<img class="transparent-logo light-scheme-logo" src="'.$logo_transparent_light.'" alt="Logo" />';
                echo '<img class="normal-logo" src="'.$logo.'" alt="Logo" />';
                echo '<img class="sticky-logo" src="'.$logo_sticky.'" alt="Logo" />';
            } else {
                echo '<img class="normal-logo" src="'.$logo.'" alt="Logo" />';
                echo '<img class="sticky-logo" src="'.$logo_sticky.'" alt="Logo" />';
            }
        echo '</a>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Add  

<a href="http://www.google.com"></a>

Around the image tag.

Comment: @MeesKluivers don't really know where they should be.

Comment: I don't really know what you mean with 'My logo' as there are multiple img tags. Wrap the <a> tag around whatever 'your logo' is.

Answer (score 0):

You did not leave enough information so I will be making some assumptions regarding your intent.

Looks like this section is just getting the url to different img files based on different criteria. So, this section should be fine untouched.

```
   <?php
     /***************************************
                SITE LOGO           
    ***************************************/
    if ( !function_exists( 'be_themes_get_header_logo_image' ) ) {
    function be_themes_get_header_logo_image() {
        global $be_themes_data;
        $logo = get_template_directory_uri().'/img/logo.png';
        if( ! empty( $be_themes_data['logo']['url'] ) ) {
            $logo = $be_themes_data['logo']['url'];
        }
        if( ! empty( $be_themes_data['logo_sticky']['url'] ) ) {
            $logo_sticky = $be_themes_data['logo_sticky']['url'];
        } else {
            $logo_sticky = $logo;
        }
        if( ! empty( $be_themes_data['logo_transparent']['url'] )) {
            $logo_transparent = $be_themes_data['logo_transparent']['url'];
        } else {
            $logo_transparent = $logo;
        }
        if( ! empty( $be_themes_data['logo_transparent_light']['url'] )) {
            $logo_transparent_light = $be_themes_data['logo_transparent_light']['url'];
        } else {
            $logo_transparent_light = $logo_transparent;
        }
```

This is the section that makes any of your different logos under the different circumstances a link. So this is where the changes will happen.

```
        echo '<a href="'.home_url().'">';
            $post_id = be_get_page_id();
            if(is_singular( 'post' ) && is_single($post_id) && isset($be_themes_data['single_blog_hero_section_from']) && $be_themes_data['single_blog_hero_section_from'] == 'inherit_option_panel') {
                $header_transparent = $be_themes_data['single_blog_header_transparent'];
            } else if((in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) && is_product($post_id)) && isset($be_themes_data['single_shop_hero_section_from']) && $be_themes_data['single_shop_hero_section_from'] == 'inherit_option_panel') {
                $header_transparent = $be_themes_data['single_shop_header_transparent'];
            } else {
                $header_transparent = get_post_meta($post_id, 'be_themes_header_transparent', true);
            }
            if(!empty($header_transparent) && isset($header_transparent) && ('none' != $header_transparent)) {
                echo '<img class="transparent-logo dark-scheme-logo" src="'.$logo_transparent.'" alt="Logo" />';
                echo '<img class="transparent-logo light-scheme-logo" src="'.$logo_transparent_light.'" alt="Logo" />';
                echo '<img class="normal-logo" src="'.$logo.'" alt="Logo" />';
                echo '<img class="sticky-logo" src="'.$logo_sticky.'" alt="Logo" />';
            } else {
                echo '<img class="normal-logo" src="'.$logo.'" alt="Logo" />';
                echo '<img class="sticky-logo" src="'.$logo_sticky.'" alt="Logo" />';
            }
        echo '</a>';
```

This will be quick, dirty and untested. I see two probable desired outcomes. First, all images should link somewhere else, this would be easiest. Change it in Settings | General. This would be the same effect as hardcoding it into your header file.

If you actually want to hardcode it, you'd do it by changing the first line of the second section.

Change

```
 echo '<a href="'.home_url().'">';
```

To

```
echo '<a href="http://www.desired-url.com">';
```

The next way is you only want a specific img condition wrapped with the new url and the default behavior otherwise in place. This requires quite a few more changes. You need to get an img set and wrap the desired link around it. Thus you'll have to compile the string to be **echo**ed then echo it at the end.

```
$logo_link = '';

$original_url_start = '<a href="'.home_url().'">';
$new_url_start = '<a href="http://www.desired-url.com">';
$url_end   = '</a>';

$post_id = be_get_page_id();

if(is_singular( 'post' ) && is_single($post_id) && isset($be_themes_data['single_blog_hero_section_from']) && $be_themes_data['single_blog_hero_section_from'] == 'inherit_option_panel') {
    $header_transparent = $be_themes_data['single_blog_header_transparent'];
} else if((in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) && is_product($post_id)) && isset($be_themes_data['single_shop_hero_section_from']) && $be_themes_data['single_shop_hero_section_from'] == 'inherit_option_panel') {
    $header_transparent = $be_themes_data['single_shop_header_transparent'];
} else {
    $header_transparent = get_post_meta($post_id, 'be_themes_header_transparent', true);
}

if(!empty($header_transparent) && isset($header_transparent) && ('none' != $header_transparent)) {
    $img1 = '<img class="transparent-logo dark-scheme-logo" src="'.$logo_transparent.'" alt="Logo" />';
    $img2 = '<img class="transparent-logo light-scheme-logo" src="'.$logo_transparent_light.'" alt="Logo" />';
    $img3 = '<img class="normal-logo" src="'.$logo.'" alt="Logo" />';
    $img4 = '<img class="sticky-logo" src="'.$logo_sticky.'" alt="Logo" />';

    $logo_link = $new_url_start.$img1.$img2.$img3.$img4.$url_end;
} else {
    $img5 = '<img class="normal-logo" src="'.$logo.'" alt="Logo" />';
    $img6 = '<img class="sticky-logo" src="'.$logo_sticky.'" alt="Logo" />';

    $logo_link = $original_url_start.$img5.$img6.$url_end;
}


echo $logo_link;
```

If the condition is opposite of what you want then swap the variables $new_url_start and $original_url_start.

Change this:

```
$logo_link = $new_url_start.$img1.$img2.$img3.$img4.$url_end;
```

To this:

```
$logo_link = $original_url_start.$img1.$img2.$img3.$img4.$url_end;
```

and

Change this:

```
$logo_link = $original_url_start.$img5.$img6.$url_end;
```

To this:

```
$logo_link = $new_url_start.$img5.$img6.$url_end;
```

Hope this helps.

Best,

Tim